# react-native redux action type isn't what's expected

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I'm using thunk to get async functionality, and for whatever reason action.type returns persist/REHYDRATE instead of FETCH_PLAYERS, how do I get into FETCH_PLAYERS switch case? Complete code:
https://snack.expo.io/@haosmark/kw-companion

I'm calling the function that fetches a list of players on component's start up

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPlayerList
}
```

This is what my actions file looks like:

```
import { FETCH_PLAYERS } from './types'
import { fetchDataAsync } from '../../api'

const data = await fetchDataAsync()

export const fetchPlayerList = () => ({
    type: FETCH_PLAYERS,
    payload: data
})
```

and lastly I have the reducer:

```
import { FETCH_PLAYERS } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    players: []
}

const playerReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  console.log(action)
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_PLAYERS: {
            console.log('fetching players?')
            return [...state, action.payload]
        }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default playerReducer;
```

Comment: All actions being dispatched go through all reducers; it is common (if you simply log actions coming into your reducers) to see all sorts of actions coming in; it is only important to switch/case the ones that are important for your reducer. Put a log into the case statement for "FETCH_PLAYERS" and see if it goes in there.

Comment: it never gets into FETCH_PLAYERS, how do I fix it so that it does?

Comment: I think in your componentDidMount in list.js, you aren't actually calling your fetchPlayerList, you need to say this.props.fetchPlayerList(), not this.props.fetchPlayerList ?

Comment: It's giving me an error, saying that fetchPlayerList is not a function

Comment: Well then dig further - if it isn't a function then log your "this.props" - what is in it? Is the function not in there? Also, have you imported the function at the top of the file in which you are referring to it?

Comment: Yes, it's imported and this.props is empty. I think I'm not connecting it correctly, but I'm not sure what the correct way would be. The link in my first post is to an expo snack with complete code and an online emulator. Can you let me know what I'm doing wrong there?

Comment: hmm ok couple of things; when you import fetchPlayerList, you should import like this: import { fetchPlayerList } from '../redux/actions/player_actions'. Next, there is a syntax error in your player_actions.js - you are using "await" but you can only use that *within* a function that is itself declared async - you can't just use await on its own like that. Try looking at that first, then that file will compile.